# Calculate the mean

Tags: statistics

For no.29
[image]
Is there a procedure to calculate the mean directly from the graph ?
I know that the mean $$= \frac{\sum x f(x)}{\sum f(x)}$$?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is correct. But what they want for your is to interpret the graph, without doing too many calculations. So let's start with the median. You need to start accumulating percentages, until you get at $50\%$. It's easy to see that both men and women get the median to be $25$ minutes, so neither $C$ or $D$ applies. But there are more women traveling below $25$ minutes than the men, or more men traveling $25$ or more minutes, so the mean travel time for men is greater.

Comment: Would you illustrate how can i calculate the median ? @Andrei

Comment: Just read the percentages off the graph, starting at one end, and when you cross over $50\%$ you have crossed the median

Comment: Add together percentages, until you get to $50$. For example, for women, step 1: $4<50$, step 2: $4+4=8<50$, step 3: $4+4+12=20<50$, step 4: $4+4+12+18=38<50$, step 5: $4+4+12+18+18=56>50$. Then the median is at $25$ minutes (step 5)

Comment: The OP formula for the mean is the weighted mean...maybe you want to hint to that